# Open Trello's Mobile site on tablet

Tags: trello

How can I open the mobile version of Trello on my tablet?

Right now it opens up the desktop version (which lags the machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading [Building trello.com for multiple devices](http://blog.fogcreek.com/building-trello-com-for-multiple-devices/) it doesn't sound like there is a separate mobile version.

> We built Trello from the ground up to work on just about any device. It’s not a simplified version with limited features, either. Trello responds to your device’s screen size and capabilities. It’s the same exact site and the same exact code; a consistent experience that looks, feels, and works the same everywhere.

You don't say what kind of tablet you have, but that blog post suggests that if you can keep increasing the font size in your browser, Trello will eventually switch to a simpler layout.

Comment: Thanks :). Sorry for the very late accepted answer. Hmmm... It's kind of hard, because I don't have greasemonkey on the tablet's browser, but maybe I can figure a hack out.

Comment: No problem at all - if you find a solution that works, do let us know here...

Answer (score 1):

I found a trick that at least works on my 7 inch tablet.

Simply rotate the display to portrait mode. Trello will automatically resize and be more mobile friendly.